# Expand partition on RHEL VM hosted on OSX

Tags: partitioning, vmware, rhel-6

I've installed a RHEL6 VM on my mac OSX. The mounted devices (`mount` on the vm) are:

```
/dev/mapper/sys-root on / type ext4 (rw,noatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,noatime)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
.host:/ on /mnt/hgfs type vmhgfs (rw,ttl=1)
```

`df -h` gives:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/sys-root   17G   16G  653M  96% /
tmpfs                 1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             237M   65M  160M  29% /boot
.host:/               466G  252G  215G  54% /mnt/hgfs
```

`/` is out of space, and I'd like to expand it. On a non-virtual machine, I'd reboot with a boot cd and re-partition.

Is there a way to expand the size of vmware volume?

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two ways (simple to harder):
 - add a new disk, or
 - Resize your disk from the outside (VMware), fiddle around with the partition table  and (probably) add another partition

And afterwards
 - create physical volume on the new disk or partition (pvcreate)
 - extend your volume group (vgextend)
 - resize your root volume (lvresize)
 - resize your root filesystem (resize2fs)